# Python generator object to list produces list too large. How to limit output size

Tags: python, list, generator

The four color-theorem states that for a connected planar graph any node can be colored such that no adjacent nodes share the same color, and that for any graph there is a solution that requires not more than four colors.

I have found Python code on stack overflow to satisfy the four-color theorem and I have incorporated that code to work with geospatial data such that no two polygons that share a border will share the same color.  The code I found for the four-color theorem returns a Python generator object (I am unfamiliar with generators)  and I convert this generator object to a Python list for further processing.  This works fine and fast on my test data of a few polygons. Since there are more than one solution to the four-color theorem I sift through the possible solutions (the list created from the generator) and find that solution that has the most even distribution of colors for the nicest cartographic effect.

Now that the code is working I tested it on a 50 polygon USA States test dataset.  Trouble is, there are so many solution to the four-color theorem that the resulting generator to list is so large that it crashes my IDE.  I am assuming that I can limit my possible solutions to a few thousand solutions and find a suitable solution with a good color distribution in that few thousand.

How do I limit the number of list items that are returned from the generator?

Below is the function that returns the generator.  How this function works and generator objects are beyond my skill level.  I do know know how to limit the number of solutions (or list items) in either the function or at the conversion to a list.

```
    def colour_map(nodes, edges, ncolours=4):
        colours = range(ncolours)
        #The edges that meet each node
        node_edges = dict((n, set()) for n in nodes)
        for e in edges:
            n0, n1 = e
            node_edges[n0].add(e)
            node_edges[n1].add(e)

        for n in nodes:
            node_edges[n] = list(node_edges[n])
        #Set to cover
        coloured_edges = list(product(colours, edges))
        X = nodes + coloured_edges
        #Subsets to cover X with
        Y = dict()
        #Primary rows
        for n in nodes:
            ne = node_edges[n]
            for c in colours:
                Y[(n, c)] = [n] + [(c, e) for e in ne]
        #Dummy rows
        for i, ce in enumerate(coloured_edges):
            Y[i] = [ce]
        X = exact_cover(X, Y)
        #Set first two nodes
        partial = [(nodes[0], 0), (nodes[1], 1)]
        for s in partial:
            select(X, Y, s)
        for s in solve(X, Y, []):
            s = partial + [u for u in s if not isinstance(u, int)]
            s.sort()
            yield s
    #call the color map function to get the generator object...
    all_solutions = colour_map(nodes, adjacent_polygons_graph, ncolours=3)

   #convert the generator object to a list
    solution_list = list(all_solutions)
```

I have tried to limit the number of yields as suggested but this returns an empty generator.

```
    yield_counter = 0
    for s in solve(X, Y, []):
        yield_counter +=1
        s = partial + [u for u in s if not isinstance(u, int)]
        s.sort()
        yield s
        if yield_counter == 100:
            break
```

Comment: Keep track of how many times you have `yield`ed a value, and stop when you reach your cutoff.

Comment: Do you want to monkey with how many are yeilded in the method, or do you want to caller to track how many have been returned and act appropriately?

Comment: ...how many have been returned and act appropriately....

Comment: How do you determine *"the most even distribution of colors for the nicest cartographic effect"*? That's the relevant code. We don't need to see the generator implementation unless you do want us to change that (if you don't, then it's just distracting).

Comment: (Hmm, ok, the implementation might be useful so we can test things ourselves. But then we'd also need input data.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the method to yield results and leave it to the caller to figure out when they have "enough" you might do conceptually something like:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        yield "hi"

results = foo()
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(results))

## or

results = foo()
enough = [next(results) for _ in range(10)]
print(enough)
```

**However,**

as was pointed out by @ShadowRanger, there is a standard package method [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) that handles this for you including guarding against `StopIteration`. This makes the manual approach superfluous.

```
import itertools

def foo():
    for _ in range(5):
        yield "hi"

enough = list(itertools.islice(foo(), 10))
print(enough)
```